# How does Spring convert a String into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, spring

I have a standard Spring class that accepts a `String` array. I know that Spring will take care of splitting a comma separated `String` into an array, but I'm unaware of how it does it under the hood.

The question that led me to this is whether the `String`s will become trimmed after being split, *but I would like to know how to see this under the hood activity as well if other future issues arise*.

```
<bean id="allServicersDelimitedLineTokenizer" 
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">

      <property name="names" value="col1,col2,col3,col4" />
</bean>
```

is the same as?

```
<bean id="allServicersDelimitedLineTokenizer" 
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">

      <property name="names" value="col1      ,     col2,      col3,     col4" />
</bean>
```

Comment: When you tried it, what did you see?

Comment: You may take a look at `StringToArrayConverter` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToArrayConverter.java

Comment: Does this need to be a question? Maybe use STS and download the source code using maven or gradle and see the code that does this/

Comment: First, I don't understand the downvote. The code was an example of the question, not the question itself. @tgkprog what you said could very well be the answer as this is what I wanted to do, but clearly I didn't know how. Not sure what else this would've been but a question...

Comment: I did not downvote you

Comment: Download STS IDE. Make a sample maven spring project Or use an existing one (you can download and use for free from github like mine https://github.com/tgkprog/samples or https://github.com/tgkprog/jCompile feel free to delete code you dont need or read up on a simple pom project and start afresh. Then once inside STS you can right click  on the project, select maven and download src and java doc. then u can debug or browse the code

Comment: SOme of these videos will help https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=maven+STS+download+code